# Error at importing xlsb file into R using excel.link

Tags: r, excel, xlsb

I am using excel.link package to read a xlsb excel file, but I am receiving a error.

The code:

```
library(excel.link)
D = xl.read.file("filename.xlsb", xl.sheet = "sheet1")
```

The error:

```
Error in COMCreate("Excel.Application", existing = FALSE) : 
  Failed to create COM object: Fail in server execution
```

Is there a way to bypass this error?

Comment: Do you have Excel installed?

Comment: Yes, I do. The function xl.get.excel() returns "An object of class "COMIDispatch"
Slot "ref":
<pointer: 0x00000201e85b7118>"